# How to populate the va_list for system error messages using the FormatMessage function?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2013, error-handling

I am unsure if I have made a fundamental issue in my implementation or there is a bug in the Windows API with regards to formatting system error messages.

I have a Windows API wrapper method for the `FormatMessage` function.  My implementation allows the caller to pass in additional parameters to allow for the formatting of system error messages.

The method signature is as follows:

`bool setFormattedMessage(int arguments, ...)`

Within this method I have the following block of code that doesn't appear to work for all my unit tests:

```
if (arguments)
{
    va_list argumentsList;
    va_start(argumentsList, arguments);

    size = FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, code, language, (LPWSTR)&buffer, 0,
        &argumentsList);

    va_end(argumentsList);
}
```

Note: 
`code` and `language` are members of the class set in the instantiation list (using `GetLastError` and `LANGIDFROMLCID(GetThreadLocale())`.

Here are some unit tests that pass without any problems:

If I create an instance of the class for an error code of 34 I will get the following if I call the method as `test.setFormattedMessage(0)` (note that this doesn't go into the block of code I posted due to the `if (arguments)` line):

> The wrong diskette is in the drive. Insert %2 (Volume Serial Number: %3) into drive %1.`

If I call the method as `test.setFormattedMessage(3, L"C:", L"disk 2", L"ABC123")` I get the following:

> The wrong diskette is in the drive. Insert disk 2 (Volume Serial Number: ABC123) into drive C:.;

However, for error messages that include such examples as `%hs` or `%08lx` I run into problems attempting to format the text.

Take the example of error code 573.  When passing an argument of 0 into the method I get the following text (as expected):

> {Missing System File} The required system file %hs is bad or missing.

But, if I pass in `(1, "test")` I end up with:

> {Missing System File} The required system file hs is bad or missing.

In fact, I have found that regardless of whether I pass in `"test"`, `L"test"`, a copy of `char`, `wchar_t` etc I always end up with the error message above.  The message created is the same as passing `(0)` with the exception of having the `%` dropped from the string.

I am finding the same problem for all other parameters unless they are numbered (such as `%1`).  I am completely stuck at this point as to whether I have made a fundamental error or there really is a shortcoming in the `FormatMessage` function.

I was under the impression that I could pass in a replacement for the `%hs` placeholder in the same way I would do it for `swprintf`:

```
char * t = "file 123";
wchar_t a[2000];
int v = swprintf(a, 2000, L"Blah blah %hs", t);
std::wstring someText(a, v);
```

> Blah blah file 123

Comment: I see no evidence at all that anything beyond `%1`, `%2` etc will be treated as a format string. Where does the docs say that it will? I think your mission here is essentially futile.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx - Find `%n!format string!` - I assumed from these remarks/notes that I could pass in ints, "short char style" (`%hs`) strings etc.

Comment: I don't read it like that at all. `%hs` doesn't fit the bill. Now, `%1!hs!` might.

Comment: The documentation doesn't appear to be explicit in regards to not supporting `%hs`.  For example, following the block I mentioned it quotes "Any other nondigit character following a percent character is formatted in the output message without the percent character. Following are some examples...".  Key part of my point "...are some examples".

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you any more.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Could you clarify?  Is it that I am really failing to read the documentation correctly?  Yes, I am not 100% confident in the documentation which is the reason why I posted the question.  Windows API offers the ability to drag out system error strings, and you can format `%1` but very likely not `%hs` placeholders.  System error strings include both styles of placeholders (plus others).

Comment: I don't see any evidence to suggest `%hs` would be formatted to anything other than `hs`. That's what the docs say to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [`FormatMessage()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx), it specifically states:

> **Security Remarks**
>
> If this function is called without FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, the Arguments parameter must contain enough parameters to satisfy all insertion sequences in the message string, and they must be of the correct type. Therefore, do not use untrusted or unknown message strings with inserts enabled because they can contain more insertion sequences than Arguments provides, or those that may be of the wrong type. **In particular, it is unsafe to take an arbitrary system error code returned from an API and use FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM without FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS**.

Your code is using `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` without using `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS`, which is not safe.

So, *unless* you are **absolutely sure** that you know the EXACT formatting of any given system error code, and your code has checked for that error code before deciding which formatting parameters to pass in, and you are **absolutely sure** that Microsoft will never change that format of that error message between OS versions, then you simply cannot safely use formatting arguments with system errors, so don't even try.  Formatting arguments are only safe to use when you use your own error messages via `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE` to access your own EXE/DLL module resources, or `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING` to provide your own error message string in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Following clarification from David Heffernan (see comments in the original question) it can be confirmed that the `FormatMessage` function doesn't support the ability to replace system error message placeholders unless they are numbered (`%1`).  Therefore, a placeholder such as `%hs` will become `hs`.

Note that the above is only true when you are not using the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS` flag.

I have checked through the system error messages using this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx

The error messages listed here do not appear to mix the placeholder styles (an error message will either use numbered placeholders or uses the alternative format).

For numbered placeholders it is possible to continue using the functionality as described in the original question.  For error messages that use the alternative style it is possible to use `vswprintf`, but only after calling the `FormatMessage` function with the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS` flag (call `vswprintf` on the populated buffer, and remember to re-initialise the va_list).

There is perhaps a weakness in the overall approach when also supporting internationalisation.  It is possible that the order of placeholders could differ across different languages.

The effort drastically increases if you *really* need to call `FormatMessage` to retrieve system error messages without using the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS` flag.  In addition to what has been described above, you can also get a C0000005 exception if your va_list doesn't match the number (and possibly types) of placeholders.